# When does the common language runtime terminate?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

There's a useful warning in the performance section on [string interning on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> the memory allocated for interned String objects is not likely be released until the common language runtime (CLR) terminates.

But: when does the CLR terminate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: the CLR terminates when the host (process) terminates.

Also, there is a default AppDomain (that is not accessible). This AppDomain would continue to exist even if your AppDomain is unloaded. This is what I think Tigran was referring to as **System**.

Comment: Could you clarify the distinction between host process and managed application, with some refs?

Comment: A host process is for example an executable, "MyApp.exe". But it also be "server" like IIS or SQL Server. In that case, they are the process and do not terminate when your application (running in an AppDomain) is unloaded/recycled. I'll get back to you with refs.

Comment: So (folding in some other reading) the hosting process starts and calls (or used to, in older versions) _CorExeMain, which loads the CLR and CRT and handles execution -- and also handles unloading the CRT and CLR before the host process terminates. That relates directly to your comment about the termination of the CLR correlating with the termination of the host process. The point you've just raised about IIS and SQL Server is important for the implicit question ("how bad is it that the CLR holds on to interned strings") -- thanks!

Comment: Refs: this is very old (.Net 1.1) MSDN article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx). But from this second link it appears that "3 AppDomain's bootstrapping" is still being used in .Net 4.0 from this link [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ebf549fa-661b-4ec5-88a4-96d033892e0c/is-there-an-appdomain-viewer-available-with-vs-2010].

Comment: Good for me, thanks. Could you edit your answer to include a comment about the host possibly being IIS (or perhaps a Windows Service) where holding on to the interned strings might be of more consequence?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good Code Project article that goes into some details about the life-cycle including CLR termination.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16164/Managed-Application-Shutdown

That article in turn is inspired by: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/08/20/51504.aspx

Comment: This seems to address how the CLR manages the shutdown of a managed process, but doesn't deal with how or when the CLR terminates? If the answer's in the second article, could you pick out and quote the relevant part? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most probababbly documentation refers to fact that CLR "thread" associated with your process will be terminated, as documentation correctly says, that inter string:

> The common language runtime conserves string storage by maintaining a
>   table, called the intern pool, that contains a single reference to
>   each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in
>   your program. Consequently, an instance of a literal string with a
>   particular value only exists once in the **system**.

and not in your application.  In fact reading further it says:

> CLR's reference to the interned String object can persist after your
>   application, or even your application domain, terminates...

So basically the storage where these data is placed goes out of your process address space, and so remains in the **system** event after your process termination.

Comment: And what is this hidden `system` that lives on in memory(?) after the process/application exits? Is it some common pool that exists for all running .NET apps and exits when every .NET app has been closed? Where did you see this information?

Comment: @leppie: is this common or where it stays precisely in memory I don't know and there is no information about that, and as you see there is no information in my answer on this. but according to the documentation, *there is* space . If this shared between different applications on the same machine, can no say either, cause there is no any evidence for that found by me. I would *presume* that yes, cause if not, don't see much reasons in *non* removing it after .NET process that actually constructs them was terminated.

Comment: I don't think this is right; I don't think the interned data goes out of my process' address space.

Comment: @TimBarrass: so does it survives after your application/domain termination ?